# ruby non-blocking tcp connection not working as expected

Tags: ruby, networking

Try to start 5 TCP sessions in a non-blocking manner. However, using wireshark, saw the TCP SYN's were sent out after 25ms from each other. Had expected to see 5 connection attempts at the same. Why?

Here is the code

```
require 'socket'


i = 0;
while i < 5
    socket = Socket.new(Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM, 0) 
    sockaddr = Socket.pack_sockaddr_in(80, '<some_homename>') 

    begin
        socket.connect_nonblock(sockaddr)
    rescue Errno::EINPROGRESS 
        #nothing to do
    end
    i += 1
end
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use threads to establish five simultaneous connections.